# What programming languages use the most favorite sites?

Tags: programming-languages, sites

I would like to know what programming languages do the most famous and lucky sites use in order to understand the consensus of todays technology (at lease for several examples). What languages use the following sites?

1. Google
2. Yahoo
3. Facebook
4. YouTube

Is the language choice depend on the time when they have started to develop their projects or the languages that they use best fits to the profile of the project?

Comment: There is an endless list of "favorite sites", and very many of them use different variations and combinations of things. There is no correct final answer to this question. Voted to migrate to Programmers.SE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I know:

- Google: Java, C++, Javascript, Python
- Facebook: PHP, Javascript, C++
- YouTube: PHP, Java, Python, Javascript
- Yahoo: Javascript, Perl, and probably Java (not sure)

Comment: im pretty sure Yahoo! also uses PHP.